Referencing instance method requires that 'srfidTagData' conform to 'PersistentModel'
So I'm currently running into an issue where when I'm using this library I'm trying to create an array of the tag data inside the model, it worked perfectly fine before with strings but I'm getting this error now from the model:

Referencing instance method 'setValue(forKey:to:)' on 'Array' requires that 'srfidTagData' conform to 'PersistentModel'

import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Model
class CycleCount {
    var date: Date
    var items: [srfidTagData] = []
    
    init(date: Date, items: [srfidTagData] = []) {
        self.items = items
        self.date = date
    }
}

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AccessOperationCode.h"
#import "RfidSdkDefs.h"

@interface srfidTagData : NSObject
{
    NSMutableString *m_TagId;
}

I tried setting the data to [] as shown, but it didn't fix anything, as well as setting srfidTagData to <Codable>:
@interface srfidTagData : NSObject <NSCoding>

Any suggestions?

If needed I can just create a new struct and use that instead of the srfidTagData in the model. This was just the easiest path.

srfidTagData Has to be Codable

I believe it also must be a value type.
